# Fatal: Illegal use of top-level '-ident' at

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have two boolean columns and I want to generate query: `WHERE f1 or f2`

I try to do at `DBIx::Class` searching for `f1 OR f2`. I tried:

```
->search([{ -bool => 'f1' }, { -bool => 'f2' }])
```

But I get error: `Fatal: Illegal use of top-level '-ident' at`

What I do wrong?

`DBIx::Class` uses `SQL::Abstract`.  But I still do not understand from the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract#Unary-operators:-bool) how to write `search` correctly.

I use `PostgreSQL` as database

SQLA version is '2.000001'
DBIx::Class v0.082841

Comment: @ikegami:  also have tried: `->search({ -or => [{ -bool => 'f1' }, { -bool => 'f2' }] })` and got same error. Notice, I am using dbix::class. Here I must provide `[]` or `{}` as first argument

Comment: Re "*Here I must provide [] or {} as first argument*", Same with SQL::Abstract

Comment: Could the problem be that it doesn't recognize `f1` or `f2`?

Comment: @ikegami: those are field names. Code is stopped when `-bool` is reached ((. I also tried: `->search([ -or => [{ -bool => 'f1' }, { -bool => 'f2' }] ]`

Comment: They're *supposed* to be field names. Could the problem be that it doesn't recognize `f1` or `f2`?

Comment: Anyway, it looks right, and without a minimal runnable demonstration (say using DBD::Sponge), that's the extent of my help.

Comment: In which column(s) are you trying to search? What is the SQL query you're expecting?

Comment: @AlexanderHartmaier: Updated. In f1 and f2 boolean columns

Comment: As I'm working with Oracle for the last 20 years I'm not familiar with boolean columns, because Oracle lacks it. Is 'WHERE f1 OR f2' valid SQL syntax in your RDBMS? I'd use search([ { f1 => 1 }, { f2 => 2 } ]).

Comment: @ikegami: Downgrading SQL::Abstract to 1.86 from 2.000001 resolves problem

Comment: A bug has been filed at https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=136984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading `DBIx::Class` from v0.082841 to v0.082842 Resolves problem

https://metacpan.org/release/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082842/source/Changes#L28

New version of DBIx::Class does not depend on SQL::Abstract any more

Answer (score 1):

Example from ilmari@irc#dbix-class

```perl
$ psql myschema

myschema=# create table bools (f1 bool, f2 bool);
CREATE TABLE

$ cat lib/MySchema/Result/Bool.pm
package MySchema::Result::Bool;

use DBIx::Class::Candy (
    -autotable => v1,
);

column f1 => {
    data_type => 'boolean',
};

column f2 => {
    data_type => 'boolean',
};

1;

$ reply -l
0> my $s = MySchema->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=myschema', undef, undef, { quote_names => 1 }); undef
$res[0] = undef

1> $s->storage->debug(1)
$res[1] = 1

2> $s->resultset('Bool')->search([{ -bool => 'f1' }, { -bool => 'f2' }])
SELECT "me"."f1", "me"."f2" FROM "bools" "me" WHERE ( ( "f1" OR "f2" ) ):
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to use "literals". This is very DB-specific, as this syntax is not supported by SQL Server or Oracle.

```
->where([\["f1"], \["f2"]]);
```

> $ perl -MSQL::Abstract -E '$s=SQL::Abstract->new; ($w, @b) = $s->where([\["f1"], \["f2"]]); say $w'

```
WHERE ( ( f1 OR f2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading SQL::Abstract to 1.86 from 2.000001 resolves problem

```
Successfully installed SQL-Abstract-1.86 (downgraded from 2.000001)
```